# Printing next string in array of pointers to strings( char *arr[ ] ) in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory

why my code doesn't print **parasyte** ?
and how printing string works when I use %s with the pointer of the first char! , shouldn't it give me an error ?

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    int main ()
    {
        char *anime[] = { "naruto", "parasyte" };
        printf ("Anime is %s \n", anime[0] + 7);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Post code as text, not a picture of text.

Comment: `anime[0] + 6` is point to `""`. Also You should not assume that the arrangement of string literals (`"naruto"` and `"parasyte"`)  on memory is in order.

Comment: Pick a language, either C or C++.

Comment: next string is just `anime[1]`. If you want to use `anime[0]`, `*(&name[0] + 1)`.

Comment: Since `goto` is a keyword in C/C++ and not a word in English, it would be best to avoid using the term in a question title about C/C++ code.

Comment: thanks all ,
it's the first time for me to put a question here and I will try to make it better and read about good questions

Comment: Reading beyond the end of a string is Undefined Behaviour - a diagnostic is not required.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: `anime[0] + 7` is undefined behavior because we can't assure inside memory that the strings going to be adjacent. Using `anime[1]` is indeed the right solution to your problem. See below comments of this answer for explanation.**

---

Because `anime[0] + 6` actually points to null-terminator instead of the next string.

Internally, your `anime` array is stored like this in the memory:

`n, a, r, u, t, o, \0, p, a, r, a, s, y, t, e, \0`

So as you can see, there is an "invisible" null-terminator at the end of `"naruto"` string.

A workaround might be to add `7` instead of `6`, so it will point to the next string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main ()
{
    char *anime[] = { "naruto", "parasyte" };
    printf ("Anime is %s \n", anime[0] + 7);
    return 0;
}
```

Or else using `anime[1]` instead, which is just way cleaner.

Comment: `printf ("Anime is %s \n", anime[0] + 7);` : I think this is _undefined behavior_.

Comment: There's no guarantee that the strings are laid out in the sequence `naruto` then `parasyte` (though I'd grant that's a probable order), nor that they are adjacent to each other (though again, it is likely that they will be).

Comment: [This example](http://ideone.com/rGE90O) shows that this answer is deceptive.  Who knows where those constants are actually placed in memory?

Comment: Just to rub the point in, I modified your code like this: `int
main(void)
{
    char *anime[] = { "naruto", "parasyte" };
    printf("n = %p\n", (void *)anime[0]);
    printf("p = %p\n", (void *)anime[1]);
    printf("Anime is %s \n", anime[0] + 7);
    return 0;
}` and when I ran it, I got: `n = 0x103e95f8a` — 
`p = 0x103e95f99` — `Anime is n = %p` — that is, one of the format strings is after `naruto` and before `parasyte`.  This happens to be GCC 7.2.0 on macOS Sierra 10.12.6, but it shows that the result you predict is anything but guaranteed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler how can that be (not adjacent)? If the strings aren't laid out in adjacent then how anime[0] and anime[1] going to be computed? I thought anime[n] is equivalent to anime+(n*sizeof(type)).

Comment: The type of the array elements is `char *`.  The values stored in the array elements are not required to be contiguous, though the two pointers in the array itself are, of course, contiguous.  I was surprised to have my point demonstrated so simply. I was expecting to find that the strings would be contiguous. In totality, they are in sorted order including the format strings, at least on my system.  I got the `p = %p` string printed using `anime[1] + 9`, for example.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I rub out above comment (I was confused). Yeah, your argument is pretty logical and I was wrong above. I just thought that at compile time that most sane compilers will lay out the strings to be adjacent to each other. :)

Comment: See [DEMO](http://ideone.com/xIfLYB)

Comment: Alright so indeed my code above is undefined behaviour. Thanks guys! I learned something new today.

Comment: I've updated above answer.